# view list from two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-function

> I have below two tables,Product and User

```
Product [PID int (PK),PName nvarchar(50)]
User [UID int (PK),Username nvarchar(50),PID (FK),LID (FK),SK nvarchar(100)]
```

> UserController has action to display a list of Users

```
 public ActionResult Details(int S)
{

    SLMEntitiesDB dbContext = new SLMEntitiesDB();
    List<User> UList = dbContext.Users.Where(U => U.LID == S).ToList();

    return View(UList );

}
```

> I want to add PName from Product table to the list and to be appears in the view.
>   I'm new to this so im searching how i could fix this
>   I tried to chnage my UserController as below

```
public ActionResult Details(int S)
{

    SLMEntitiesDB dbContext = new SLMEntitiesDB();
    var VL = (from U in dbContext.Users
                     join P in dbContext.Products
                     on U.PID equals P.PID
                     where P.PID == U.PID
                     select U).Where(U => U.LID == S).ToList();

    return View(VL);

}
```

> but in Details View i can't see the property of Product Model
>   Details View

```
@model IEnumerable<SLMDemo0.Models.User>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
    </tr>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName) // here i can't type item.PName, because PName in Product model not in user model
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
</table>
```

> I also created a function on Sql but i don't know how to call it and to be viewed in the details view

Comment: I think your list must be: `var VL = (from U in dbContext.Users
                     join P in dbContext.Products
                     on U.PID equals P.PID
                     ).Where(w => w.LID == S).ToList();`

Comment: You need to create one `ViewModel`